# regex to combine tags

Tags: java, regex

I have an xml output as shown below

```
 <B-company> The  British </B-company> <I-company> Broadcasting  Corporation is a </I-company> <B-Type> public  </B-Type> <I-Type> service  broadcaster </I-Type> <HQ> headquartered   </HQ> <B-company> at  </B-company> <I-company> Broadcasting  </I-company> <B-Type> House  </B-Type> <I-Type> in  </I-Type> <HQ> London  </HQ>
```

Here B-tag represents Begin Tag and I-tag shows continuation tag /end tag(if no further I-tag is found).

I am looking for something like this as an output

```
<company> The  British Broadcasting  Corporation is a </company> <Type> public   service  broadcaster </Type> <HQ> headquartered   </HQ> <company> at  Broadcasting  </company> <Type> House in  </Type> <HQ> London  </HQ>
```

i.e. The characters 'B-' need to be removed from the first tag thus forming  and all the tags until we have '/I-' tag and add  in the end. How do we achieve this in java regex.

Comment: [Use an XML parser instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2773311) Something about parsing XML/HTML with regexes...

Comment: @Arc676 It can hardly be called "parsing" if the output is xml. These look like basic string operations, it's just that the string happens to be xml.

Comment: @Rawing, you are right. Its just basic strings encoded with some tags. Its does not follow the normal xml convention. The use of XML parser seems to me like an overkill for this. Hence the regex approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
</[BI]-(\w+)>\s*<I-\1>|(</?)[BI]-(\w+>)
```

and replace with `\2\3`.

[Online demo.](https://regex101.com/r/8HVUVp/2)

---

What it does:

`</[BI]-(\w+)>\s*<I-\1>` matches a closing tag immediately followed by a continuation tag. None of this text is captured in groups 2 or 3, so all text matched by this will be removed.

`(</?)[BI]-(\w+>)` then matches the remaining tags that start with `B-` or `I-`. It captures the text around the `B-` or `I-` in groups 2 and 3, so by replacing with `\2\3`, the `B-` or `I-` is effectively removed.

Comment: The online demo site helped a lot. Its was something I was looking to exp my naive-regex skills on.

Comment: Thank you a lot, for both asking and for providing the correct answer! It was very helpful since I am also doing some transformations on the XML with IOB tags.